# How do you layer GraphicsObjects in a window with Zelle's graphics.py?

Tags: python, tkinter, zelle-graphics

Using Zelle's graphics.py module, how do you alter the layering of `GraphicsObject`s that are already drawn to a `GraphWin` window? By my understanding, `GraphicsObject`s are layered in the order that they were drawn with `draw()`, with shapes drawn later being displayed on top of shapes previously drawn, and the [graphics.py documentation](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf) I use does not offer any way to change this order afterwards. Given code such as this:

```
win = GraphWin("Test", 500, 500)

square = Rectangle(Point(70, 70), Point(200, 200))
square.setFill("Lawn Green")

circle = Circle(Point(100, 100), 50)
circle.setFill("Tomato")

square.draw(win)
circle.draw(win)
```

...which produces a window like this:
[window opened when program is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVAJe.png)

...how do I make it so that `square` is displayed on top of `circle` later on? i.e. `circle` is "sent to the back" or `square` is "brought to the front," like how you can manipulate shapes in, say, Microsoft Word.

I did some research and found that the `tkinter.Canvas` class, from which `graphics.GraphWin` inherits, has `tag_raise()` and `tag_lower()` methods that do what I described above with `tkinter.Widget` objects, so I tried running:

```
win.tag_raise(square)
```

...but nothing happened (not even an error was raised). I reasoned that that may be because `square` is not an instance of `Widget`, so then I naively tried to alter my `graphics.py` file so that `GraphicsObject` inherits from `Widget`:

```
# Source code imports tkinter as tk
class GraphicsObject(tk.Widget):
```

...but that caused my previous line `win.tag_raise(square)` to throw an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\Python Projects\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\Python Projects\test.py", line 17, in main
    win.tag_raise(square)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2937, in tag_raise
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'raise') + args)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1658, in __str__
    return self._w
AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no attribute '_w'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should use `win.tag_raise(square.id)` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 I feel silly now. It works!! Thank you so much.